# How to Dynamically (Hard Coded) the context menu

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to Dynamically (Hard Code) the Context menu in my .cs file instead of defining it inside my .xaml file.

So far I have defined the datagrid inside .cs file like this:

```
        DataGrid dgCM = new DataGrid();
        dgCM.Style = (Style)FindResource("DgCustomStyle");
        dgCM.ItemsSource = MainWindow.m_DtTagList.DefaultView;



        dgCM.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.All;
        dgCM.VerticalGridLinesBrush = Brushes.Black;
        dgCM.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgCM.CanUserAddRows = true;
        dgCM.CanUserDeleteRows = true;
        dgCM.IsReadOnly = false;



        dgCM.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
        dgCM.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;


        dgCM.MouseDoubleClick += DgCM_Row_DoubleClick;

        dgCM.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Now My aim is to define in similar way the Context menu for it having 3 options Copy, paste and delete when I right click. 
Could someone suggest me a solution for it? 
Looking forward for your replies. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that by adding following code:

```
 MenuItem copy = new MenuItem() { Header = "_Copy" };
 copy.Click += (s, e) => 
 { 
    // Do something 
 };
 MenuItem paste = new MenuItem() { Header = "_Paste" };
 paste.Click += (s, e) => 
 { 
    // Do something 
 };
 MenuItem cut = new MenuItem() { Header = "_Cut" };
 cut.Click += (s, e) =>
 {
    // Do something 
 };
 dgCM.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
 dgCM.ContextMenu.Items.Add(copy);
 dgCM.ContextMenu.Items.Add(paste);
 dgCM.ContextMenu.Items.Add(cut);
```

Comment: I'm glad that you could use it